# How to use liblinear with weka gui?

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka, liblinear

I am using weka to build one model. I have requirement of using liblinear for our model. For testing using weka GUI, I need to add liblinear jar into my classpath but after adding liblinear jar in classpath, Weka GUI still give me error liblinear classes not found. I have searched through internet and found nothing.
Is there anybody else who face same problem as me. Also, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that to use liblinear in weka gui, you have ti install weka-3-7 version. Then click on tools--> package manager--> install liblinear.